# How to run a command in unix shell and then get the output back from/to java application

Tags: java, shell, io

I know how to execute a shell command from my java app.  It should be something like:

```
String command = "java -version";
Process proc = null;
try {
  proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}
catch (IOException e) {
System.out.print(e);
}
```

I want to get the output of this command back to my java app, without printing the output to some temporary file which I then read from my app.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use ProcessBuilder

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
"C:\\PathToExe\\exe.exe","param1","param2").start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;

System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", Arrays.toString(args));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

code that is already found on stackoverflow Execute external program in java

Comment: Note that processbuilder has nothing at all to do with the solution, which is simply to use the getinputstream method in the process class.